# Why My PHP code is not working to show UTF-8 from mysql?

Tags: php, android

This is my code

```
$sql = 'SELECT * from customer';
  $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
  $statement->execute();
  if($statement->rowCount())
  {
    $row_all = $statement->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    echo json_encode($row_all);         
  }  
  elseif(!$statement->rowCount())
  {
    echo "no rows";
   }
```

it show "????".when retrieve from thai alphabet.where i have to fix code in the linecode? thank you so much

Comment: [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: By the way, to easily handle the output on the front-end / receiving end, you should also send back json in case no rows were found.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this code in the first line in your php file

```
header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the following queries before your query.

```
$connection->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$connection->query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
```

Comment: Thank you so much,It's work.

Comment: @ManaRuT please mark tick my answer if you found it helpful to you :)

Answer (score 0):

you can update your table column collation type to "utf8_general_ci" if you want to insert any Thai symbol on it